# How to order more than one view in xib file iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, xib, nib

In my nib file there are three views, I don't  show all of them at the same time.

Please take a look at this picture :
[image]

**of course the real situation is more complicated than this picture because i have other subviews (buttons , labels ...) in each view.**

actually it is very hard to maintain this file because all the views override each other !

is there any suggestion ?

thank you

Comment: What's the question? What were you _originally_ trying to do before you got yourself into this situation?

Comment: Do you always show exactly one of them at a time? Do you sometimes show two of them and sometimes three of them? Suggested solutions will depend upon knowing what you're up to.

Comment: @matt , yes that is right sometimes I show two of them and some times one of them.

Comment: so for example if I want to change the location of one of the subview in one of this views, may I should move a lot of other subviews..

Comment: also it is very hard to see all of this views one override the other

Comment: why don't you hide unnecessary views and adjust the required views using `setFrame`?

Comment: Is the problem in your _program_ (managing the views) or is just that right now they are hard to see when designing the interface because they are in the same _nib_? Still not clear what the problem is.

Comment: exactly ... that is my problem

Comment: Which one? I gave you two different choices!! I ask "problem 1 or problem 2" and you say "yes"??? Try to be helpful please.

Comment: aaa sorry ,,, hard to see when designing the interface...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I'm going to assume that you mean you are having trouble managing the views while *designing them in the nib file*.

If so, I have two possible suggestions.

- In your screen shot, all three views are listed at the left (View, View, View). When you want to work on one of them, drag its "View" listing to the bottom of the list. This brings the view in question to the front so you can work on it and its subviews.
- This is what I would do: keep each view in its own nib! That way you can design it without the others in your way. When the app launches, use code to load all three nibs in turn, pulling each view out and sticking it into your real interface.

Comment: Here are my instructions for how to make a nib that contains just a UIView (and its subviews) and how to load it in code and stick it into your interface: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_outlet_connections

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case below is what I would have done.

My assumption is all three views are of size 320 x 480 (considering iPhone 4)

let's say you have three views as below.

1. View 1 >> view001
2. View 1 >> view001
3. View 1 >> view001

What I would do is add a scrollview `mainScrollView`.

Now let's consider you want to show `view001` only.

```
- (void) showView001Only {
    view001.hidden = NO;
    view002.hidden = YES;
    view003.hidden = YES;
    mainScrollView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Now let's say you want to show two views as `view002` and `view003`. In this case I would have added both views in scroll view and add one below each other.

```
- (void) showView0023Only {
    view001.hidden = YES;
    view002.hidden = NO;
    view003.hidden = NO;
    mainScrollView.hidden = NO;
    [mainScrollView addSubview:view002];
    view002.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
    [mainScrollView addSubview:view003];
    view003.frame = CGRectMake(0,480,320,480);
    // now set mainscrollview content size to 320x960
    [mainScrollView setContentSize: CGSize(320, 960)];
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

If you want to show both views on same screen without scrolling then I would say its all depend on what you have in view1 and view2.

Comment: thank you for your response, but actually that not my problem I can hide and show them, my problem that it is hard to see them and adjust them in the xib interface.... do you have any other suggestions ! thank you

Comment: @user3516596 :  could you please explain what exactly you want to do? may be we can help you in that way... edit the question and add what you exactly want to do... giving just example is not clear with us...

Comment: How could I disparate the three views in three nib files with one controller !!